# display php result in html page

Tags: php, html

how to display php result in html file?
this is my index.html file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My PHP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
This is HTML code
<?php
include("blabla.php");
?>
Back into HTML
</body>
</html>
```

and i want to display the blabla.php result in index.html
but the result when i execute the index.html is

```
This is normal HTML code Back into normal HTML
```

thanks before :)

Comment: what is the content of blabla.php?

Comment: Unless "blabla.php" has a "print" or "echo" statement, nothing will be displayed. We'd be able to help more if you posted more code!

Comment: Where does the word "normal" come from before the word "HTML"? It's not in your code... Weird.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ: that's interesting indeed :D

Comment: It's unlikely that `index.html` will be interpreted as PHP so `<?php include("blabla.php"); ?>` won't execute (won't display either since it looks like a malformed tag as far as any markup interpreter would be concerned). It would work if the file is called `index.php` and is running on a webserver.

Comment: html files doesn't accept php code.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ the normal wording is a CSS `:before { content: 'normal';` style `:-D`

Comment: @Martin there's no CSS class/id on the "HTML" word for that to happen... Plus there's no linked CSS in OP's post.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I'm afraid I was being vaguely dry humoured.

Comment: @briosheje just json result

Comment: @hd sorry, i delete "normal" in This is normal HTML code Back into normal HTML

Comment: @CD001 i dont know it must index.php :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run PHP in .html files because the server does not recognize that as a valid PHP extension unless you tell it to. To do this you need to create a .htaccess file in your root web directory and add this line to it:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

This will tell Apache to process files with a .htm or .html file extension as PHP files.
 for more info please read this http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm

Answer (score 0):

The page should be index.php not index.html in order to execute php script.

Comment: so, its cant use include in html?

Comment: You can't "include" by PHP (you can import some other extension file like js, css), unless you change the extension of the file or like mamta suggest by telling the server to process an html file as an php file.

Answer (score 0):

The main page should be saved with a file extension of `.php` to properly retrieve and execute the php files included.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use PHP, your files will have to have the file extension `.php`.

Are you running your code in a server environment or development environment like XAMPP ? There are guides available like [this one](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-XAMPP-for-Windows) to install XAMPP for windows which will help you get started.

Once you have XAMPP setup  go to the installation location and then to the folder called htdocs, create a folder and call it test.

Then move both index.php (Rename it from index.html) & blabla.php (again renaming with the `.php` extension) to the newly created test folder.

Then head over to your web browser and go to localhost/test/index.php and you will hopefully see your webpage as you expect to see it on the screen!

Answer (score 0):

If the file name already ends with a ".php" extension, it is just a matter of have the php code echo or print the result in a place where you would normally write the code.  If it does end with the ".html" extension, just be sure to change the extension to ".php". I have provided a simple example that looks similar to the one you quoted below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
          <?php
        echo "Blah, Blah, Blah";
          ?>
        </p>   
    </body>
</html>
```